# Java Web Start security warning alternative

Tags: java, security, automation, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a shell script that automates a bunch of things. One of the things it needs to do is run a javaws script. Right now it runs as follows in the shell script:

```
javaws /tmp/jnlpgenerator-cli
```

This causes the security warning to pop up which says :

> The website certificate cannot be verified. Do you want to continue?

This shell script is part of an automation tool, so what can be done to modify the above command so that no user interaction is needed?

Answer (score 1):

(One of the very few situations where) a policy file might be best.  See the following for more information:

- [Signing Code and Granting It Permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/index.html)

  - [Set Up a Policy File to Grant the Required Permission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep3.html)
- [Policy File Creation and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyGuide.html)
- [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)